# find and replace regular expression rather than full string

Tags: python, regex, json

I've loaded a dictionary of "regex":"picture" pairs parsed from a json.

These values are intended to match the regex within a message string and replace it with the picture for display in a flash plugin that displays HTML text.

for instance typing:

```
Hello MVGame everyone.
```

Would return:

```
Hello <img src='http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-1a1a8bb5cdf6efb9-24x32.png' height = '32' width = '24'> everyone.
```

However:

If I type,

```
Hello :) everyone.
```

it will not parse the `:)` because this is encoded as a regular expression `"\\:-?\\)"` rather than just a string match.

How do I get it to parse the regular expression as the matching parameter?

Here is my test code:

```
# regular expression test   
import urllib
import json # for loading json's for emoticons
import urllib.request # more for loadings jsons from urls
import re # allows pattern filtering for emoticons

def loademotes():
    #Create emoteicon dictionary
    try:
        print ("Trying to load emoteicons from twitch")
        response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/emoticons').read()
        mydata = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

        for idx,item in enumerate(mydata['emoticons']):
            regex = item['regex']
            url = "<img src='" + item['images'][0]['url'] + "'" + " height = '" + str(item['images'][0]['height']) + "'" + " width = '" + str(item['images'][0]['width']) +  "' >"
            emoticonDictionary[regex] = url
        print ("All emoteicons loaded")

    except IOError as e:
        print ("I/O error({0}) : {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
        print ("Cannot load emoteicons.")

emoticonDictionary = {} # create emoticon dictionary indexed by words returns url in html image tags

loademotes()

while 1:
    myString = input ("Here you type something : ")

    pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(emoticonDictionary.keys()) + r')\b')
    results = pattern.sub(lambda x: emoticonDictionary[x.group()], myString)
    print (results)
```

Comment: What regular expression syntax do the values in the JSON dictionary use? Is it compatible with the Python regex dialect at all?

Comment: No idea I can't find any information out, I wasn't aware that regex wasn't standardised. Info on the json I get back with the regex in is here https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/chat.md

Comment: Most regular expressions engines use *very similar* syntax. Changes are that the expressions returned here are simple enough to work unaltered. But without documentation about this you are essentially flying blind.

Comment: From what I can tell the \\ are double escaped, ie escaped once and then again so "\\:-?\\)" is actually "\:-?\)" as a parseable regular expression. How would I get this to occur in my code ?

Comment: That's just escaping the escape sequence. Don't confuse the representation with the value. The actual *value* is just `\:-?\)`.

Comment: I mean perhaps escaping the sequence once, and then parsing it would work.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to escape the string sequence once and return the escaped string? .decode('string-escape') doesn't appear to work in python 3.x

Answer (score -1):

I think you could make sure each syntactic character in regular expressions is surrounded by character classes before you feed it to the re.  Like write something that takes :)  and makes it [:][)]